# RegEx match only the innermost arrays in a JSON string

Tags: javascript, regex, json

First off, this is about displaying the JSON to the user in a friendly format, so **accessing the parsed JSON object is not going to help**.

**I know that the JSON object in JS can pretty-print the JSON for me**, however, I need to modify that output slightly, that's what this question is about.

In the JSON (Pretty-printed by `JSON.stringify()`):

```
{
  a:[
    {
      c: [
          "c",
          "d"
        ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How would I match only 

`[
  "c",
  "d"
]`?

Lazy regex (`/\[(?:\S*\s*)+?\]/g`) matches

```
a: [
    {
      c: [
          "c",
          "d"
        ]
```

Which is no good.

I'm hoping to remove the whitespace from the innermost arrays, to get something like this from the initial JSON:

```
{
  a:[
    {
      c: ["c", "d"]
    }
  ]
}
```

The accepted answer did exactly what I initially asked for, but I forgot to mention that there is whitespace between the elements of the array as well, so a regex replace doesn't appear to be an option.

Instead, I used the regex provided to match the strings, then looped through the matches and removed the whitespace from each match, then replaced the initial match in the JSON data with the new string.

Here is the code:

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify(obj, null, 2);
var matches = jsonData.match(/\[\s*[^\[\]]*?\s*\]/g);
jsonData = matches.reduce(function (json, match) {
    return json.replace(match, match.replace(/\s/g, ""));
},  jsonData);
```

Comment: Matching by regex when the situation involves counting some sort of container markers like parentheses or brackets is hard, and in general not really possible. "Regular expressions can't count" is the rule I learned in Automata Theory (a very long time ago, admittedly). It's a task that requires a more powerful type of recognizer/parser.

Comment: @Pointy, the above link clearly demonstrates that RegEx is capable of this.

Comment: @PaulS. Read the comment I added at the top, I have to parse the JSON for pretty printing.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Yes it can, but it adds unnecessary white space which i'm trying to remove with this regex.

Comment: @KthProg note the comments - Perl "regular expressions" aren't really "regular expressions" in the formal sense.  That said, I guess matching just innermost groups (ignoring, possibly, the complexity of some escaping mechanism for brackets) can be done. (If the innermost value involves a string constant with a bracket in it, things would get weird.)

Comment: What *exactly* is the output you are trying to achieve?  What is the input you are working with?  It seems like you are possibly overcomplicating/overengineering this problem.

Comment: @RocketHazmat The output I am looking for is now indicated just before the Perl regex link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\[\s*([^\[\]]*?)\s*\]
```

would match only the innermost `[...]` and capture everything between leading and trailing whitespace in group 1, so if you replace that by `[$1]`, you'll get your desired result.

```
result = subject.replace(/\[\s*([^\[\]]*?)\s*\]/g, "[$1]");
```

Test it [live on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/tH7rW3/1).

In essence, it's a less complicated version of what the solution you found is doing, with the added benefit that it works in JavaScript. The problem with the other one is that `.` can never match a newline in JavaScript, unlike in other languages - if you substitute `[\s\S]` for `.`, that regex will also work (but is overkill for the problem here).

Comment: Did you use the exact code I posted? `\s*` is already matching the linebreaks.

Comment: I see the problem. It's my bad for not explaining the format of the string better. There is also whitespace between the elements of the arrays which has to be removed. I updated my question to show this.